# Is there a specific commercial or experimental implementation of the Carnot cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

I have been unable to find an example of a Carnot engine implemented practically, beyond the drinking bird (which has not revolutionized technology as far as I know). I understand the Stirling and Rankine engines work with similar cycles, but can a real-life model be made and implemented using Carnot cycles?

There may be a working approximation, such as the following article presents, which I would take as a yes to my question as long as it follows the Carnot cycles requirement of 2 adiabatic and 2 isothermal cycles:
https://c21.phas.ubc.ca/article/heat-engines-in-the-real-world/

Edit: For clarity, I know the Carnot cycle is reversible, but the Stirling cycle is also reversible and has a direct practical application. Reversible does *not* mean it cannot have a practical application as an engine.

*(A similar question was asked 6 years ago and has not been answered)*

Comment: A quick search for `experimental carnot cycle` on Google Scholar, for example, yields examples such as Zhai et al., "[Experimental implementation of finite-time Carnot cycle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.10153.pdf)." It's not clear if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That does cover the experimental implementation part of the question somewhat.